# Vtiger CRM Pick list Dependencies

Tags: vtiger

How to add picklist dependencies values in vtiger crm

I need to add picklist dependencies for demo version of vtiger

Comment: Is there anything you tried? Can you share it? As you are new, I strongly advice you reading our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Follow this link ,
https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Picklist_Dependency_Setup

Answer (score 3):

login with admin user got to CRM Settings => Studio => Picklist Dependency Setup => 
Click on "Add Picklist Dependency" button 
select module where you can add picklist Dependency.
Select Source Field and Target Field